# Node.js running MySQL queries with async

Tags: mysql, node.js, asynchronous

How to run a loop query inside an async query?

```js
let someRows1, someRows2, someRows3, otherRows1;

    .then( rows => {
        someRows3 = rows;
        someRows3.forEach(function (element) {
            database.query( 'UPDATE  `orders` SET `amount` = "' + element.value + '" WHERE `id` = "' + element.id + '"' );
        });
    })
    .then( () => {
        // do something with someRows and otherRows
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `for await...of` [link to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of)

Comment: "for await ... of " still a draft and not completed supported

Comment: then you could use `async\await` and usual loop